# SQL Query returning multiple values

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to write a query that returns the time taken by an Order from start to completion.

My table looks like below.

```
Order No.   Action      DateTime
111         Start       3/23/2018 8:18
111         Complete    3/23/2018 9:18
112         Start       3/24/2018 6:00
112         Complete    3/24/2018 11:10
```

Now I am trying to calculate the date difference between start and completion of multiple orders and below is my query:

```
Declare @StartDate VARCHAR(100), @EndDate VARCHAR(100), @Operation VARCHAR(100)

declare @ORDERTable table
(
    order varchar(1000)
)

insert into @ORDERTable values ('111')
insert into @ORDERTable values ('112')

Select @Operation='Boiling'

set @EndDate = (SELECT DATE_TIME from PROCESS WHERE ACTION='COMPLETE' AND ORDER in (select order from @ORDERTable) AND OPERATION=@Operation)

---SELECT @EndDate

set @StartDate = (SELECT DATE_TIME from PROCESS WHERE ACTION='START' AND ORDER in (select order from @ORDERTable) AND OPERATION=@Operation)

---SELECT @StartDate

SELECT DATEDIFF(minute, @StartDate, @EndDate) AS Transaction_Time
```

So, I am able to input multiple orders but I want to get multiple output as well.

And my second question is if I am able to achieve multiple records as output, how am I gonna make sure which datediff is for which Order?

Awaiting for your answers. Thanks in advance.

I am using MSSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can aggregate by order number and use `MAX` or `MIN` with `CASE WHEN` to get start or end time:

```
select
  order_no,
  max(case when action = 'Start' then date_time end) as start_time,
  max(case when action = 'Completed' then date_time end) as end_time,
  datediff(
    minute, 
    max(case when action = 'Start' then date_time end), 
    max(case when action = 'Completed' then date_time end)
  ) as transaction_time
from process
group by order_no
order by order_no;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split up your table into two temp tables, cte's, whatever, and then join them together to find the minutes it took to complete

```
DECLARE @table1 TABLE (OrderNO INT, Action VARCHAR(100), datetime datetime)

INSERT INTO @table1 (OrderNO, Action, datetime)
VALUES 

(111         ,'Start'       ,'3/23/2018 8:18'),
(111         ,'Complete'    ,'3/23/2018 9:18'),
(112         ,'Start'       ,'3/24/2018 6:00'),
(112         ,'Complete'    ,'3/24/2018 11:10')



;with cte_start AS (
SELECT orderno, Action, datetime

FROM @table1
WHERE Action = 'Start')
, cte_complete AS (
SELECT orderno, Action, datetime

FROM @table1
WHERE Action = 'Complete')

SELECT 
start.OrderNO, DATEDIFF(minute, start.datetime, complete.datetime) AS duration

FROM cte_start start

INNER JOIN cte_complete complete
    ON start.OrderNO = complete.OrderNO
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you attempt to approach this problem with a set-based solution? After all, that's what a RDBMS is for. With an assumption that you'd have orders that are of interest to you in a table variable like you described, `@ORDERTable(Order)`, it would go something along the lines of:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
      [Order No.]
    , DATEDIFF(
        minute,
        FIRST_VALUE([DateTime]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Order No.] ORDER BY [DateTime] ASC),
        FIRST_VALUE([DateTime]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Order No.] ORDER BY [DateTime] DESC)
      ) AS Transaction_Time
FROM tableName
WHERE [Order No.] IN (SELECT Order FROM @ORDERTable);
```

This query works if all the values in the `Action` attribute are either *Start* or *Complete*, but also if there are others in between them.

To read up more on the `FIRST_VALUE()` window function, [check out the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/first-value-transact-sql).

**NOTE:** works in SQL Server 2012 or newer versions.